# Non-greedy regex matching in ed (editor)

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, ed

I am looking at a line of a file I opened with ed and displayed with `.p`:

`First sentence. Another. One. Text continues`

Now I want to replace the string `First sentence.` with `replacement.` However, the command

`.s/.*\./replacement./`

acts in a greedy manner, that is, it replaces `First sentence. Another. One.` by `replacement`, and not just `First sentence.` as desired.

How can I do a non-greedy replacement in ed?

Comment: This has been asked many times. Hint: non-greedy matches (like `.*?`) are your friends. Even better in this context is an exclusive character class, like `[^.]*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `ed` supports non-greedy matching, but assuming it does not:

You want to match everything except a dot.

```
.s/[^.]*\./replacement./
```

Comment: Be aware that `.` won't match across line breaks (it's *"every character but `\n`"*, really), while `[^.]` *will* of course happily match across line breaks. This might not be an issue with `ed` but it can lead to unexpected results in other contexts.